# Troubles while practicing python(new to programming)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I decided to learn python and I chose the book "The python book" to do so but I encountered a problem while coding one of the exercise programs, I'm doing a program that shows how control structures work but it gets stuck in a while loop, I think it is because a boolean variable (isint) is not setting to true so it just gets stuck there, but I'm not sure because I'm new to programming.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2
import sys
target_int=raw_input("How many integers? ")

try:
    target_int=int(target_int)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit("You must enter an integer")

ints=list()
count=0

while count<target_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
if isint==True:
    ints.append(new_int)
    count+=1

print("Using a for loop")
for value in ints:
    print(str(value))

print("Using a while loop")
total=len(ints)
count=0
while count<total:
    print(str(ints[count]))
    count+=1
```

I would get this result everytime I ran the program:

```
jonathan@Jonathan:~/Python$ ./construct.py
How many integers? 1
Please enter integer1:2
Please enter integer1:3
Please enter integer1:4
Please enter integer1:4
Please enter integer1:23
Please enter integer1:13
```

As you can see no matter what I put there the while loop just keeps going.

Comment: You never modify `isint`, so it will always be `False`. Therefore, the `if` statement will never get executed, meaning `count` will never be modified, meaning your `while` loop will run forever.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that, but being a total novice at this language I thought it was ok to leave it like that because that's the way it was written in the book, besides it said that once the while statement ended it was going to become true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indentation is important in python:

```
while count<target_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
if isint==True:
    ints.append(new_int)
    count+=1
```

This is two separate blocks of code: the `if isint==True:` part is not inside the `while count<target_int:` block.

You need to change it to this:

```
while count<target_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
    if isint==True:
        ints.append(new_int)
        count+=1
```

Additionally, `isint` is never set to anything but `False`, anywhere. So the body of your `if` statement is never going to execute.

You probably want to set `isint` to `True` when you know the input is a valid integer.

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot, this newbie embarrassment feeling is getting me now

Answer (score 1):

You aren't setting `isint` flag to true when checking for an integer.

```
while count<target_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
        isint=True
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
    if isint==True:
        ints.append(new_int)
        count+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

First your indentation looks wrong for:

```
if isint==True:
    ints.append(new_int)
    count+=1
```

Then you should add `isint = True` in (at the end of) the block

```
try:
    new_int=int(new_int)
```